# Processing performance: background-color vs static picture

Tags: html, css

I tended to put plain color in a big div (960x1250 px) with dashed border. So, I have 2 solutions I applied:

1. Use `background-color` and `border:` CSS tag
2. Use static PNG-8 image

I have tested both of them but I could not really see the different. Do anybody experiment the performance of web browser when using tag `background-color` versus static picture?

Thanks for your advance answer.

Comment: I vote for first solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only probable difference is in the time it takes the browser to fetch the image. Compared to that, the rendering time is negligible.

When you test, make sure the image is fetched remotely, not from the browser cache. When fetched remotely, I predict the image option will be much slower.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer the first solution.

A few bytes of CSS compared to many kilobytes of image data (even if the image is small and repeated) is nothing for loading and caching on client side. On slow (mobile) systems it's even better to use CSS because it's rendered even faster then an image. It's even important for accessibility to use CSS instead of static images but the major effort is, that this is faster for both loading and processing.